# Whitelist multiple domains in content security policy

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am writting a chrome extension that needs to have two domains in its whitelist for the content security policy. I've looked at the official docs, but I still can't seem to figure out the proper syntax.

The following does not seem to work:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://foo.com https://example.com; object-src 'self'"
```

**EDIT:**

Both my content script and my popup are able to reach foo.com, however, neither can reach example.com.

Are chrome extensions capable of having multiple sources whitelisted in the CSP?

Comment: Content scripts are not affected by the extension's CSP, but by the page's.

Comment: Edited my answer extensively; please verify that my example extension works for you, and that you are not performing any of the mistakes I detail in my answer.

Comment: Are you actually trying to reach `example.com`? The actual `https://example.com` has two problems: first, it redirects to `https://example.iana.org/`, and second, it uses a certificate not appropriate for its domain, causing Chrome to block it. (You definitely get a warning screen when you type in the URL. I'm not sure how it handles script resource requests, but I'm guessing it blocks them.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From what I know about CSPs, this looks syntactically correct. The [HTML5 Rocks article on CSP](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) agrees with your syntax, saying:

> `script-src https://host1.com https://host2.com` would correctly specify both origins as valid.

However, your problem may be that either:

1. This CSP [disallows all subdomains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/CSP/Using_Content_Security_Policy#Example_3), including `www.foo.com` and `www.example.com`. You can add those subdomain hostnames explicitly, or you can use `https://*.foo.com` to allow all subdomains.
2. If any of your script requests redirect to a non-permitted domain, the request will fail. For example, if `https://example.com/foo.js` responds with a `301` or `302` redirect to `https://notpermitted.com/foo.js` (not-permitted origin) or `https://www.example.com/foo.js` (non-permitted subdomain), the request will fail [according to the spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html#script-src):

   > Whenever the user agent fetches a URI (**including when following redirects**)... if the URI does not match the allowed script sources, the user agent must act as if it had received an empty HTTP 400 response...

**EDIT:**

Just to confirm, yes, Chrome extensions can whitelist multiple HTTPS origins. You can build a simple extension to test this:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name":"CSP Test",
    "version":"1.0",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup":"csp_test.html"
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.iana.org https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**csp_test.html**

```
<script src="https://www.iana.org/_js/2013.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="csp_test.js"></script>
```

**csp_test.js**

```
alert(jQuery)
alert(jQuery.ui)
```

This extension loads jQuery and jQuery UI from remote domains. If you remove either origin from the CSP, you will see an "`undefined`" alert signifying that one of the libraries failed to load.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help. The domain I was trying to contact had some weird redirect rules which was enforcing HTTP under certain conditions.

Comment: very insightful answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same problem to **whitelist** the secure resources URL's with the below warning.

> There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
>   
>  « Ignored insecure CSP value "object-src" in directive 'script-src'.
>   
>  « CSP directive 'object-src' must be specified (either explicitly, or implicitly via 'default-src') and must [whitelist only secure resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelisting).

To resolve HTTP [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src) use below key value in [`manifest.json`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) file.

```json
{
"content_security_policy":
   "script-src 'self' https://yash.test.com:8443 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' https://yash.test.com:8443"
}
```