# Why isn't jQuery loading into my Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is a Chrome extension which replaces the user's new tab screen.

My jQuery isn't loading because the 'hello' in my HTML isn't alerting. Should I be loading jQuery in the manifest or the HTML? Whichever it is, I presume the HTML should be in the same place.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Some title",
  "description": "Some description.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },

"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["newtab"],
      "css": ["style.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("hello");
        $(function(){
            $('#container').masonry({
            // options
            itemSelector : '.item',
            columnWidth : 300
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- etc -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load scripts from remote locations in chrome extensions without explicitly specifying permission in `manifest.json`, you can either specify permissions in `manifest.json` or download jquery and distribute your extension with jQuery file. Second option (having local copy of jquery in extension folder) seems much more reasonable.

Comment: I've tried the second option - and I'm loading it via both content scripts and HTML as above - but CSS won't load in content scripts and jQuery won't load at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the index.html is your background page then I would add jquery to the extension folder and reference it relatively.

If its applied to pages then specify a content script as described right [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Again, keep it local and relative.

Comment: As per my code above, I have a content script but it's not working because if I remove the CSS link tag from my HTML, no CSS is loaded.

Comment: So the index.html you are referring to is a network resource ala http://www.ibm.com? If this is the case then you don't need to add a script tag at all, whenever you URL 'matches' pattern  is working the content scripts are loaded.

Comment: The index.html is the page that shows every time I create a new tab.

Comment: You need to whitelist the googleapis.com domain. Look this question for an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789426/whitelist-multiple-domains-in-content-security-policy  . I believe all calls need to use https.

Comment: Can't I just host it locally?

Comment: Totally,  add the lib to your build folder and ref it in the content script declaration, check the link in my answer.

Comment: See my code above. Is that what you're talking about? It's still not loading.

Comment: The code above is still pulling it from a server. Also your content script entry in the manifest should ref jquery.min.js and not jquery.js